# mongodb replica choose operation to sync

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I'm starting using mongodb in replica mode.
Is there a way to choose which kind of operation I want to sync from master to secondary?

```
For example if i want to perform ONLY insert from primary to secondary BUT DON'T WANT TO performe the delete actions is it possible?
```

Thnx!!!

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization between replica set nodes is performed by MongoDB. As a user of the database you do not get to choose which operations get synchronized - they all do.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the replica set! But, you can have MongoDB instance what "tails" your primary MongoDB servers OpLog and do just inserts to that instance. Check [here.](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/tailing-mongodb-oplog-sharded-clusters)